# CodeIgniter - Routing doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I have a routing problem in CodeIgniter.

I can access to my default controller (the login page) with the `http://localhost/MySite`. So I think the routing configuration is good.

When I submit the login form of my login page, I get a `Not found` error 404 and the URL displayed is `http://localhost/MySite/login`?

When I insert "index.php" (`http://localhost/MySite/index.php/login`) in the url, it works.  In the documentation it's written that I must add some lines in `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What is wrong with this URL Routing?

Comment: Have you fill blank the `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: I have `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this thing which i am using write now in my project........

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work. I'll give you a precise : the directories structure : a directory (the name of the project : MySite) under the document root of Apache. Under this directory : 'system' for CodeIgniter, 'application' for the code and 'assets' for the javascript, image and css files.

Comment: I am also using same like that only project Name->application,system,css,js,images,fonts,.htaccess,index.php files and folders......for me i am not facing any problems.........

Comment: I tried this with my own computer (I am now with the one at work), it works. I have a big question : why do the 'default_controller' route work while the form action which follow the same mecanism doesn't ? (Why do this work at home while not at work ? not the same OS, not exactly the same apache and php configuration...). Thnak you for your answer... If you'll have another idea... ^_^

Comment: I am also new to this field.......if you find any help from my answer please don't for get to Upvote.........

Comment: I don't forget... I'm here at home : works like a charm !! grrr !!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

I hope it will be ok.

Comment: And assign empty string to $config['index_page'] which is found in your "application/config" directory

Comment: Snif... Not ok. It seems the .htaccess is ignored when it's a form action... How to be sure that .htaccess is read ?

Comment: I always do that in my application. I always use base_url() in form action and never use index.php. It always be ok.

Comment: Good idea ! I will do this and go back to give you a result.